# How can I update a <h:panelGrid> when am clicking in another <h:panelGrid>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For example, I am trying to update total price in a `panelgrid` once am clicking on another panelgrid.

```
<c:forEach items="#{coinsBean.selectedCountryVo.selectedGameVo.operatorGamePackageVos}" var="operatorGamePackageVo" >

    <h:panelGrid id="pack_#{operatorGamePackageVo.id}"
                 styleClass="bord" 
                 style="border:solid #cbcbcb; margin: 4vmin;   min-width: -webkit-fill-available;text-align: center;border-radius: 2vmin;" 
                 onclick="selectUcs(this.id);"
                                 >                                       
        <p:commandLink  style="border-radius: 2vmin; padding: 2vw;background-size: 4vmin;text-align: center;font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif "  
                        update="totalSelected"   action="#{coinsBean.selectOperatorGamePackageVo(operatorGamePackageVo)}"
                        value="#{operatorGamePackageVo.packageName}"
                                       />

    </h:panelGrid>
</c:forEach> 

<h:panelGrid columns="1" id="totalSelected" style="background-color: white;                             
             padding-left: 5vh;border-radius: 0  0 1vh 1vh;margin-bottom: 2vh;width:95%;margin:auto;text-align: left ;">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p id="total" style="color: #FE6D2C;font-size: 3.5vmin;font-family:  'Cairo', sans-serif;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;margin: auto;" dir="rtl">
            price
        </p>

        <p id="total1" style="color: black;font-size: 3vw;font-family:  'Cairo', sans-serif;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;margin: auto" dir="rtl">
                        #{coinsBean.selectedCountryVo.selectedGameVo.selectedOperatorGamePackageVo.price}

        </p>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

once I click on the above one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

It isn't possible to add ajax to a `h:panelGrid` (see *Explanation* to see why).

Probably the best way to this would be using the `h:commandScript` (since JSF 2.3).

Just add this somewhere to your page:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandScript name="someFunction" render="totalSelected" />
</h:form>
```

Now when you want to update the panelGrid just execute `someFunction()`.

In your case add this to your panelGrid that should update the other one:

```html
<h:panelGrid ... onclick="someFunction();">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

One could also use css (a bad hack) to stretch a `h:commandLink` to fit the whole panelGrid (I can add this on request).

---

### Explanation

Basically every component (`h:panelGrid`, `h:commandLink`, etc.) you can use is a java class. But not every one can/should do the same things. If you want to use ajax behaviours with a component that specific component has to implement the `ClientBehaviourHolder` interface. This is reserved for action components like `h:commandButton`, `h:inputText`, `h:commandScript`, etc. . The `h:panelGrid` does not implement this interface.